# Why do vulnerable packages not update correctly?

Tags: npm, npm-install

To give an example: I get a warning like so about a dependency:

*Regular Expression Denial of Service in braces*

*Package: braces*

*Patched in >=2.3.1*

*Dependency of popper*

I've tried updating popper and braces and chokidar all to their latest versions, but their versions in package-lock aren't changing and the vulnerability warning isn't disappearing. What do I need to do to actually correct their versions properly?